# Why `init` of shim in my require.js configuration not called?

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js, requirejs, csrf

**Update**:

I was writing a small module to handle this csrf token problem in *backbone* until I got push notification of @Louis's answer.

His answer is quite elegant and seems nice, but I'll leave [a link](http://github.com/kuc2477/backbone.csrf) to my *backbone.csrf* module github repo just for anyone who needs it.

====================================================================

I'm using **Backbone** as my frontend framework along with my **Django** backend.

I had to configure my `Backbone.sync` to set CSRF request header for every single AJAX requests before it sends it, for compatibility with Django's CSRF protection system.

Since I was using **require.js** for modular javascript development, I tried to configure this in `shim.init` of `require.config` so that this overriding will be fired as soon as the Backbone is loaded on browser:

```
<script>
    var require = {
        ...

        shim: {
            'jquery': {'exports': 'jQuery'},
            'backbone': {
                'deps': ['underscore', 'jquery'],
                'exports': 'Backbone',
                'init': function(_, $) {
                     alert('NOT EVEN CALLED');
                     var originalSync = this.Backbone.sync;
                     this.Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
                         options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
                             xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', window.csrf_token);
                         }
                         return originalSync(method, model, options);
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
// Load require.js
<script src="require.js"></script>
```

Although the Backbone has been successfully loaded, the 'init' of the require configuration doesn't get called.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html), I see that Backbone calls `define` when it detects it is running with an AMD loader. Using a `shim` with a module that calls `define` results in undefined behavior because `shim` is for modules that *do not call `define`*.

You could achieve what you want with a fake `backbone` module like this which you'd save in a file named `backbone-glue.js`:

```
define(['backbone'], function (Backbone) {
    var originalSync = Backbone.sync;
    Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
        options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', window.csrf_token);
        }
        return originalSync(method, model, options);
    };

    return Backbone;
});
```

And then you should have a map like this in your configuration for RequireJS:

```
map: {
     '*': {
          backbone: 'backbone-glue'
     },
     'backbone-glue': {
          backbone: 'backbone'
     }
}
```

What this does is that everywhere (`*`) when the module `backbone` is required RequireJS loads `backbone-glue` instead. However, in `backbone-glue`, when `backbone` is required, then `backbone` is loaded. This allows `backbone-glue` to load the original Backbone.